# Distribute $ value over records in the same location

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, math

I have a table with location, ID, expense type, and cost.
There are three certain expense types that needs to be distributed over the others.

Example data [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64533/3)

In the example data, only one location is shown for simplicity.

The three type values `x`,`y`,`z` are the types to be distributed over the other types (`a->e`).

The distribution needs to be in three stages, one for each of the three types, and have an audit trail that shows how much of Type `x` went to each Type, then `y` and `z`.  Order is `x -> y ->z`.

The distribution is based on the grouped sum of each Type, so in the example data, the groupings are

```
a - 31.3
b - 15
c - 68.4
d - 57.3
e - 55.3
```

the value of `x` is `-12.7` The distribution formula is 
`aDiff =  (a*(x / (a+b+c+d+e)))`

`aDiff` is then evenly split over each `a` Type.  In this example, `aDiff` is `-1.74`, so since there are two `a` values, ID 101 would be 10.5 + (aDiff/2) resulting in `9.63` with an audit value of `-0.874`

Anyone know how to go about this?  I'm struggling on where to start with an sql script to do this.

EDIT:
Updated SQL Fiddle with latest code.  Issues i'm finding are when applying this to full data set the values are incorrect.  The sum of A-Z of the original data should equal the sum of A-E in the new data, but it doesn't.  Not sure what's going on at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is by 1) Creating a function to perform the inner calculation, 2) Use the function in left self join. The some of the values you posted in your question are different than the values in the SQL Fiddle, so I went with the values in the fiddle.

Also, it's unclear how you are supposed to calculate your audit value because 9.63 + -.874 = 8.756, not 10.5, so I performed that calculation as (aDiff/2).

I hope this helps.

```
--Step1: Create a function that calculates the xDiff distribution formula, aDiff =  (a*(x / (a+b+c+d+e)))

IF OBJECT_ID('aDiff_fn','fn') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION aDiff_fn
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[aDiff_fn] (@a decimal(10,6))
RETURNS decimal(10,6)
AS
BEGIN

RETURN

@a *
(
    (SELECT sum(cost)
    FROM expenses
    WHERE [type] = 'x')
/

    (SELECT sum(cost)
    FROM expenses
    WHERE [type] in ('a','b','c','d','e'))
)
END
GO

---Step2: Compare original values and the aggregates using a self JOIN

SELECT
    e.Location,
    e.ID, 
    e.[Type],
    e.Cost,
    g.CountOfType,
    g.TotalCostOfType,
    g.aDiff,
    e.Cost+(g.aDiff/g.CountOfType) AS yValue,
    (g.aDiff/g.CountOfType) AS AuditValue
FROM
    expenses AS e
LEFT JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        [type],
        count([type]) AS CountOfType,
        sum(cost) AS TotalCostOfType,
        dbo.aDiff_fn(sum(cost)) AS aDiff
    FROM
        expenses
    GROUP BY
        [type]
    ) AS g
    ON e.[type] = g.[type]
```

Comment: The -0.874 audit shows the change applied.  Old value 10.5, new value 9.63, change due to X is -0.874.  Once other values are added in, you would be able to see that X resulted in a change of -0.874, Y resulted in a change of -4, and Z resulted in a change of +1.  I'll have a play with your code.  You can check SQL Fiddle for the code i'm currently using.